# HttpWebResponse failing due to "unable to read data from transport connection"

Tags: c#, selenium-chromedriver, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I'm using Selenium to try and test for broken links using the code below. The idea being that I'll create an Http Request and check the Response's status code. However I'm finding that whilst the driver can navigate to the any page on the site, the code is falling over at `request.GetResponse()`

```
private const string BASE_URL = "https://something.example.com"

        using(IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver())
        {
            brokenLinks = new List<string>();
            //navigate to home page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(BASE_URL);

            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(BASE_URL);
            
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            response.Close();
       }
```

The error being returned is simply `Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host` which gives me no indication as to what the problem might be.

I've tried changing the Base URL to point to another site (e.g. a news site) and the response seems to work fine - which leads me to believe this may be a problem on the server of some sort - any pointers at all would be appreciated

Comment: "Forcibly Closed" means the TCP connection did not complete.  It usually means on of following 1) The Server was started before the client 2) The client and server are using different port number 3) The client is trying to connect to the loopback address 127.0.0.1 (or local host which is configured for loopback).  4) The server and client are both using same IP address.  The server should listen to IP Address.any.  Client should connect to machine IP address (or name).  5) You are trying to use IPV4 instead or IPV6 (or opposite).  IPAddress is an array.  Index zero is IPV6, index 1 is IPV4

Comment: Also better to use `HttpClient` instead of outdated `HttpWebRequest`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding the following code prior to creating the  response fixed the issue:

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;                    
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(link);
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```